# Convert Unix Time column to UTC in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix-timestamp, utc

I have an imported table with a column of Unix timestamps.  I'd like to convert the column to UTC time.  This is what I have so far.

```
select dateadd(S, [startime], '1970-01-01') from table
```

This returns the output in the desired format, but I'm not sure how to make a permanent change to that column...If that's even possible.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? (MySQL has a built-in function for that conversion: `from_unixtime()`)

Comment: MSSQL.  Matthew solved this for me.

Comment: By definition, Unix time *is* UTC.  Perhaps you actually mean some sort of display format conversion?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a new buffer column.

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD [starttimeDT] DATETIME
```

Then update the value of that buffer column.

```
UPDATE [tablename] SET starttimeDT = dateadd(S, [startime], '1970-01-01')
```

Then drop the old column, once you check that all the data is right (make sure you do that, since once you delete the column there is no going back).

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] DROP COLUMN starttime
```

Then rename the buffer column to have the old name.

```
sp_rename 'starttimedt', 'starttime', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: @user3638757 Great! Glad to help. Please accept this answer to help people in the future looking for similar solutions, not to mention, to get this post out of the unanswered queue.